# WCF & SOAP Headers - How to ensure that the default header elements are not signed in a request?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, wcf, soap

Having a problem with WCF - connecting to a Weblogic service where the SOAP headers dont need to be signed - i.e. < TO >, < ACTION >, < MessageID > and other WS-Addressing elements - are not required to be signed. In the request WCF is signing these by default anyway, which wouldn't be a problem except it's then expecting them to also be signed in the response, and I get this exception returned from WCF:

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException: 

The 'To', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing' required message part  was not     signed.\r\n\r\nServer stack trace: \r\n   at 

System.ServiceModel.Security.WSSecurityOneDotZeroReceiveSecurityHeader.ExecuteMessageProtectionPass(Boolean hasAtLeastOneSupportingTokenExpectedToBeSigned)\r\n   at 
System.ServiceModel.Security.ReceiveSecurityHeader.Process(TimeSpan timeout, ChannelBinding channelBinding, ExtendedProtectionPolicy extendedProtectionPolicy)\r\n   at 
System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityProtocol.ProcessSecurityHeader(ReceiveSecurityHeader securityHeader, Message& message, SecurityToken requiredSigningToken, TimeSpan timeout, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState[] correlationStates)\r\n   at
System.ServiceModel.Security.AsymmetricSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingMessageCore(Message& message, String actor, TimeSpan timeout, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState[] correlationStates)\r\n   at System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityProtocol.VerifyIncomingM....
```

I'm using a CustomEncoder and Custom Behaviours for other elements of the webservice client but cant seem to disable signing of the default elements through this route - I've tried accessing the below in IEndpointBehaviour

```
public void AddBindingParameters(ServiceEndpoint endpoint, System.ServiceModel.Channels.BindingParameterCollection bindingParameters)
{
   ChannelProtectionRequirements requirements = bindingParameters.Find<ChannelProtectionRequirements>();
   requirements.IncomingSignatureParts...
   requirements.OutgoingSignatureParts...
}
```

But the number of `HeaderTypes` in these collections is always zero for me at the Message behaviour stage in the WCF process.

Also, in an attempt to access `MessageHeaderAttribute` in IClientMessageInspector I've tried to add the following but to no avail.

```
 public object BeforeSendRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel)
{
     int headerIndex = request.Headers.FindHeader("To", "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing");

}
```

Here's my config -

**config in XML**

```
<binding name="CUS_BINDING" >
      <transactionFlow />
      <security defaultAlgorithmSuite="TripleDesRsa15"
                authenticationMode="MutualCertificate"
                messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity10WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12BasicSecurityProfile10"
                requireDerivedKeys="false"
                messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncrypt"
                securityHeaderLayout="Lax"
                allowSerializedSigningTokenOnReply="true"
                enableUnsecuredResponse="true"                     
                    >

        <secureConversationBootstrap authenticationMode="CertificateOverTransport"
                                   messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10"
                                   requireDerivedKeys="false"
                                        />
      </security>
      <customTextMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10"  />
      <httpsTransport requireClientCertificate="true" />
    </binding>
```

**Config adjusted in code**

```
public static CustomBinding GetServiceBinding()
    {            
        //Get custom binding reference from app.config
        CustomBinding binding = new CustomBinding("CUS_BINDING");
        binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15, 0);
        binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15, 0);
        // Reference the asymettric security element            
        AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement securityBindingElement = binding.Elements.Find<AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement>();
        // Get the x509ProtectionParams from the security element
        X509SecurityTokenParameters tokenParameters = new X509SecurityTokenParameters();
        tokenParameters.X509ReferenceStyle = X509KeyIdentifierClauseType.IssuerSerial;
        tokenParameters.RequireDerivedKeys = false;
        tokenParameters.InclusionMode = SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToRecipient;

        securityBindingElement.InitiatorTokenParameters = tokenParameters;
        //securityBindingElement.ProtectionTokenParameters = tokenParameters;
        securityBindingElement.LocalClientSettings.DetectReplays = false;

        //Set timestamp to false as it's not in the request
        securityBindingElement.IncludeTimestamp = false;
        // Added during testing, permanant fixture
        securityBindingElement.RequireSignatureConfirmation = true;
        securityBindingElement.MessageSecurityVersion = MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10;            

        return binding;
    }
```

So I need to be able to do one of two things via any method possible -

1. Turn off signing on the client's request for these header elements so that they're not expected to be signed in the incoming reponse or
2. Tell WCF to ignore the lack of a digital signature in the response XML and proceed

Answer (score 1):

This was asked some time ago but I found this question in my search for a solution.

So here is what worked for me. Just set the enableUnsecuredResponse="true" in the custom binding.

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="WsHttpSoap11" >          
        <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10" />            
        <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" enableUnsecuredResponse="true"></security>
        <httpsTransport/>
    </binding>
  </customBinding>
```

Answer (score -1):

My initial hunch is that there is some way to make the requirements.IncomingSignatureParts path work. But the fallback is to simply turn off ws-addressing all together (e.g. use message version "Soap11") and add them manually in a message inspector / encoder.